# How to create an object of type boto3.resources.factory.s3.ObjectSummary from a .csv file in python?

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am writing a unit test in python for a function that takes an object from an S3 bucket as the input parameter.

The input parameter is of type `boto3.resources.factory.s3.ObjectSummary`.

I don't want my unit test to access S3.

I am writing a test that reads a .csv file into an object of type

`pandas.core.frame.DataFrame.`

Does anyone know how I can create an object of type boto3.resources.factory.s3.ObjectSummary from it?

Thanks for your response.

Comment: I recommend looking at moto: https://github.com/spulec/moto

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to fix my problem with this

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)

```py
# builtins
from unittest.mock import patch

# 3rd party
import pandas as pd

with patch("boto3.resources.factory.s3.ObjectSummary") as patched_obj:
    patched_obj.return_value = pd.DataFrame()
    # run test in this scope
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to respond, but this is not what I am looking for. I need to create an objet of type boto3.resources.factory.s3.ObjectSummary.

Comment: Anytime and sorry, re-reading, it looks like it's backwards from what you're looking for! If moto is a solution for you, you can post what you did as an Answer to gain reputation and help others with the same or a similar question!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jordanm. I was able to solve my problem like this

```
import unittest from io 
import StringIO 
import boto3 
import pandas as pd from moto 
import mock_s3

class GetBindingsTester(unittest.TestCase):

@mock_s3  # mocks all calls to S3
def testGetBindings(self):
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3_resource.create_bucket(Bucket="mock_bucket",
                          CreateBucketConfiguration={
                              'LocationConstraint': 'us-west-1'})

    dts_mapping_file = pd.read_csv(r'dtsMapping.csv')
    csv_buffer = StringIO()
    dts_mapping_file.to_csv(csv_buffer)
    s3_resource.Object("mock_bucket", 
        'dtsMapping.csv').put(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
    obj = s3_resource.Object("mock_bucket", "dtsMapping.csv")
```